# Scroll issue (z-axis) on web page being viewed with Ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile

I've builds a rails app which also utilized jQuery mobile, but I am experiencing a weird issue when viewed on the ipad when a user side scrolls or scrolls from top to bottom to much. Its hard to explain, but basically with the sidescrolling the page begins to rotate into the screen on the z-axis with some bluish textures backround being shown. I tried disabling sideswipe w/ jquery but then that prohibites the user from scrolling from side to side on the page to view the rest of it. Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior?